# Call to undefined method mysqli::result()

Tags: php, mysql

Can you help me guys to figure out my error, thank you for helping.

> Call to undefined method mysqli::result()

```
<?php

    function user_exists($username) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
        $query = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'");
        return ($db->result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: What are you attempting to return from this function? As the error says there is no mysqli::result() method

Comment: take a quick look at [mysqli api](http://php.net/mysqli), mysqli does not have method called result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
    function user_exists($username) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sample");
        $result = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE username = '$username'");
        return ($result->num_rows ? true : false);}
```